# Update operation in Kendo UI grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am implementing a grid in Kendo UI and for Update and Delete, I am using the popup mode of Kendo UI. I am trying hard but unable to achieve the flow correctly but unable to do so. I want to write custom popup that I have done with below code.

```
editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    template: kendo.template($("#editData").html()),
    confirmation: function(dataRow) {
        return 'Are you sure you want to remove the record with Id: ' + dataRow.recId;
    }
},
```

With this it is showing me popup with my HTML code. Also for custom delete message I write confirmation attribute of editable tag. My query is how to capture the event of update and delete, or call my function when user go for Update and delete operation. And want to make an AJAX call on that operation for which I wrote the code as below

```
    update: {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/productSeries/getDataList"
    },
    destroy: {
        type : "POST",
        url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/series/retireData",
        dataType : "text",}
```

but unable to bring the control in to the AJAX call. Please let me know what is the wrong I am doing here.

Comment: Does your popup include a button that tells the data source to save changes?

Comment: @Brett No there in no button in my popup. It is having standard update and cancel button provided by the kendo UI.